# JavaScript: How to Define a Non-Enumerable Method without using Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, enumerable

I want to add a method to Object, but now all arrays and object have it. When I use `for(.. in ..)`, it is enumarated and this is a problem for my software. So, I need to make my method non-enumerable.

I know there is a `Object.defineProperty()`, but it is not supported by old browser (which are still around) and even latest versions of Konqueror.

Is there another way to make a method non-enumerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That's why it's considered bad practice to use JavaScript's `for..in` without immediately checking for `hasOwnProperty`. I.e., you should always do:

```
for (var item in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Tools like [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) will report an error in your code if you use `for..in` without a `hasOwnProperty` check.

Answer (score 0):

For ECMAScript 3 (used in old browser), you cannot change the enumerable attribute.
If you want to filter the method, maybe you can check the type of the object in for(..in..).